# Why is id different through id() and through the cheat engine?

Tags: python, cheat-engine

When I run the code and then check the variable id using the cheat engine, they are different, why?

Here's what i have:

```
import time

x = 500

while True:
    time.sleep(1)
    print(f'ID: 0x{format(id(x), "X")}\nValue: {x}')
```

[code result and cheat engine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rmtl4.png)

Comment: `id()` gives you the address of the Python object - which will include its reference count, link to the type that defines the object, and possibly other fields prior to the actual object data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "cheat engine" is showing you the location of the data itself.  The `id` is the address of the integer object.  Each object (even integers) has structure overhead.